# While loop in php error

Tags: php, while-loop

Well since the foreign key doesn't even working in phpMyadmin i've decided to use the while-loop just to put some value in the table who has the fk. and here's the error i have encountered..

Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /mnt/Target01/338270/

> honestly, i've been working out with phpMyadmin for over a year but this is the first time this dramatical error occured.. and i really got so upset about it.. if you guts know what to do please tell me.. T^T

Comment: You've got a bug. Care to show us what you've written?

Comment: a) endless loop b) takes too long to execute

Comment: ask smarter, give as portion of code that actually do the error.

Answer (score 0):

See this [set_time_limit](http://php.net/set_time_limit), and also this [memory-limit](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit)

Comment: It's more likely that the OP's while loop isn't ending, so increasing the execution time limit will just mean that it takes longer before they get the timeout... and there's no mention of memory problems, so why increase that?

Comment: thanks mister mark, here is my code..

$i=1;
while ($i >= 0) {


$sql2 = "INSERT INTO gb_education (appinfoid,level_name,sy_start,sy_end,level_address,level_honor)

values

('$i','$_POST[elem]','$_POST[estart]','$_POST[eend]','$_POST[eaddress]','$_POST[ehonor]')";

$i++;
}